# Adding route into routing table using agent

Tags: unetstack

We planned to do final year project in the area of 
underwater routing protocol (multi-hop communication) using UnetStack. In planned routing protocol, every node has to select its next hop out of many available neighbours. Before going in depth about selection of next hop algorithm, i would like to see how i can configure selected next hop in routing table using UnetStack.For that purpose i installed 5 nodes. Node 1 and 5 are destination and source nodes respectively. Neighbors of node 5 are node 3 and 4.Out of neighbors 3 and 4 , i would like to select node 3 as next hop of node 5 to reach destination.
I am not able to add node 3 as next hop at node 5. It will be helpful, if you providing some input regarding this.

I writen simuation script as follows:

```
channel.soundSpeed = 1500.mps           // c
channel.communicationRange = 100.m     // Rc

// run the simulation infinately
simulate  {
 // Destination node
node '1', remote: 1101, address: 1, location: [ 0.m, 0.m, 0.m], shell: true, stack: { container ->
container.add 'routing', new org.arl.unet.net.Router();
container.add 'rdp', new org.arl.unet.net.RouteDiscoveryProtocol();  
} 

node '2', remote: 1102, address: 2, location: [ 0.m, 0.m, -75.m], shell: 5102, stack: { container ->
container.add 'new_routing_agent', new new_routing_agent();
container.add 'routing', new org.arl.unet.net.Router();  
container.add 'rdp', new org.arl.unet.net.RouteDiscoveryProtocol();
}    

 // neighbor node for node 5, and will be a next node for node 5 during routing
node '3', remote: 1103, address: 3, location: [0.m, 0.m, -90.m], shell: 5103, stack: { container ->
container.add 'new_routing_agent', new new_routing_agent();
container.add 'routing', new org.arl.unet.net.Router();  container.add 'rdp', new org.arl.unet.net.RouteDiscoveryProtocol();   
}

//Neighbor node for node 5 ,but not a next node for node 5
 node '4', remote: 1104, address: 4, location: [0.m, 0.m, -150.m], shell: 5104, stack: {container ->
container.add 'new_routing_agent', new new_routing_agent();
container.add 'routing', new org.arl.unet.net.Router();
container.add 'rdp', new org.arl.unet.net.RouteDiscoveryProtocol();    
}

// Source node
node '5', remote: 1105, address: 5, location: [0.m, 0.m, -160.m], shell: 5105, stack: {container ->
container.add 'new_routing_agent', new new_routing_agent();
container.add 'routing', new org.arl.unet.net.Router();
container.add 'rdp', new org.arl.unet.net.RouteDiscoveryProtocol();    
  }
}
```

Agent: new_routing_agent as follows:

```
class new_routing_agent extends UnetAgent {
    def router;
    int addr;  
        // STARTUP  
   void startup() 
    {

        def phy = agentForService Services.PHYSICAL;
        subscribe topic(phy);

        router = agentForService Services.ROUTING;
        subscribe topic(router);

        def nodeInfo = agentForService Services.NODE_INFO;
        addr = nodeInfo.address; // obtain the address of the node

        def rdp = agentForService org.arl.unet.Services.ROUTE_MAINTENANCE
        def rsp = rdp << new RouteDiscoveryReq(1)      // discover routes to node 1

    }

    void processMessage(Message msg) {  
    if (msg instanceof RouteDiscoveryNtf )  
    { 
        if (addr == 5)
        addroute 1, 3 ;

        else if (addr == 4)
        addroute 1, 2;

        else 
          addroute 1,1;     
    }  //End of if   
} //End of processMessage
} // End of class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Router` agent is all you need, if you plan to populate your own routes. To add a route, you send a `RouteDiscoveryNtf` to the router agent. This is what the `addroute` command does, but that only works on a shell (not in an agent).

This simple example code shows how you can implement your own `addroute()`:

```
void addroute(int to, int via) {
  def router = agentForService Services.ROUTING
  router.send new RouteDiscoveryNtf(to: to, nextHop: via)
}
```

The `RouteDiscoveryProtocol` agent manages routes for you, which is perhaps not what you want, if you're developing your own routing protocol.

Comment: I don't know why but I'm always getting a failure and so processMessage is not even being called

Comment: What are you getting a failure on doing?

Comment: FYI ... UnetStack 3.1 now supports EditRoute message that allows you to add/delete/edit routes dynamically