# Dynamic Routing in UNET Stack

Tags: groovy, unetstack

I'm trying to create a simulation in UNET Stack in which I have a route and I send packets from that from one node to another through the given route.

I do not want to use add route in simulation but instead as I create nodes dynamically i.e once I create nodes they themselves figure out the route. Is this possible to create a agent and how can I do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that by sending `RouteDiscoveryNtf` to the `router` agent. For an example of how to do this, see previous discussion on [Adding route into routing table using agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56013376/adding-route-into-routing-table-using-agent)

Comment: I have done almost the same. But when I type routes in the command shell I do not get anything. So how do I check if the routes are added to the routing table ?

Comment: If you're running in real time mode and have a shell open to the specific node, you should be able to see the routes with the "routes" command.

Comment: FYI ... UnetStack 3.1 now supports EditRoute message that allows you to add/delete/edit routes dynamically